# Use github actions to merge code and build files in branch with altered gitignore

Tags: github, github-actions

So I deploy my site using composer.  Composer pulls down an entire repo by branch name.  I want to develop using a main branch with a .gitignore that ignores the build folder of a React app. When Composer deploys I use a different branch one that has the .gitignore allowing the build folder.  When I push to the main branch I would like to merge main into compiled-main checkout compiled-main delete the .gitignore and run yarn install yarn build

- git checkout master
- merge master -> compiled-master
- git checkout compiled-master
- rm .gitignore
- mv compiled-gitignore .gitignore
- yarn install
- yarn build
- git add .
- git commit -m 'message'
- git push

Here are my actions:

```
build:
name: Build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: checkout master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@master
  - name: Merge master -> compiled-master
    uses: devmasx/merge-branch@v1.3.1
    with:
      type: now
      from_branch: master
      target_branch: compiled-master
      github_token: ${{ github.token }}
  - name: checkout compiled-master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: compiled-master
      persist-credentials: false
  - run: |
      rm .gitignore 
      mv compiled-gitignore .gitignore
      yarn install
      yarn build
      git config --local user.email 'xxx@xxx.edu'
      git config --local user.name 'xxx'
      git add .
      git commit -m "Add new gitignore & build"
  - name: Push changes
    uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.Secret_Bot_token }}
      branch: 'compiled-master'
```

Unfortunately everything works until I try to push the build files and the new .gitignore up to the compiled-master branch. I am getting a message that the url for the repo is not accessible.  However if I click the link directly from the error the repo url resolves???

<strike>Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nxxx/xxx-react-app/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL</strike>

So at first I got the error above. So I edited my secret to be very simple so I knew it would not send any character that might bust the encoding.  So it seems I no longer get the invalid url message now I get the error:
"remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx-react-app.git/'
Error: Process completed with exit code 128."
But I have checked the username and it is correct.  Maybe after changing the secret it takes time to work?

Also tried this:

```
build:
name: Build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: checkout master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@master
  - name: Merge master -> compiled-master
    uses: devmasx/merge-branch@v1.3.1
    with:
      type: now
      from_branch: master
      target_branch: compiled-master
      github_token: ${{ github.token }}
  - name: checkout compiled-master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: compiled-master
      persist-credentials: false
      fetch-depth: 0
  - run: |
      rm .gitignore 
      mv compiled-gitignore .gitignore
      yarn install
      yarn build
      git config --local user.email 'xxx.edu'
      git config --local user.name 'xxx'
      git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.Secret_Bot_token }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git
      git add .
      git commit -m "Add new gitignore & build"
      git push
```

The repo I am trying to run these commands in and push to is a private repo. But I thought that is what the secret code is for. everything is running in the same repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the `devmasx/merge-branch@v1.3.1` action, you need to replace

the line `github_token: ${{ github.token }}`

with  `github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Next, since you are getting error in commiting files I would recommend you to use

```
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
  with:
    commit_message: Add new gitignore & build
    branch: compiled-master
```

So finally your new code should be:

```
build:
name: Build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: checkout master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@master
  - name: Merge master -> compiled-master
    uses: devmasx/merge-branch@v1.3.1
    with:
      type: now
      from_branch: master
      target_branch: compiled-master
      github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  - name: checkout compiled-master branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: compiled-master
  - run: |
      rm .gitignore 
      mv compiled-gitignore .gitignore
      yarn install
      yarn build
  - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
    with:
      commit_message: Add new gitignore & build
      branch: compiled-master
```

You can read more about secrets [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, and it did not break anything but it did not fix the error.  It seems in my case the code for the merge works whether using github.token or secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN I will leave it as secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN as you suggest.  Original issue still remains the code for the push is failing for authentication.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Tell me if that worked.

Comment: So still getting a problem with authentication now the error says: Run stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
Started: bash /home/runner/work/_actions/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action/v4/entrypoint.sh
INPUT_REPOSITORY value: .
INPUT_STATUS_OPTIONS: 
INPUT_BRANCH value: compiled-master
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
Error: Invalid status code: 128

Comment: Can you try removing the lines:
`persist-credentials: false`
and
`fetch-depth: 0` .
I have updated this in my answer as well. I guess the error is due to `persist-credentials: false`